# SMTP timeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, timeout

My rails application features a mailing system, using smtp.

My application runs perfectly on localhost and in production at my office and at home. But at a corporate office where there is a firewall, I was connected via ethernet, and the mailing system failed and something went wrong. I was not sure of the error at that time as it was on production and I couldn't see the error message. I had no time to test on localhost.

At another corporate building, using their guest wifi, and I was trying to send mail to the users on localhost, I got a timeout error, but it worked perfectly on production website. 
This is the error that I got:

```
Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize'
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `open'
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `tcp_socket'
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `block in do_start'
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:549:in `do_start'
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mail-2.5.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:136:in `deliver!'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mail-2.5.3/lib/mail/message.rb:2033:in `do_delivery'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mail-2.5.3/lib/mail/message.rb:229:in `block in deliver'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:415:in `block in deliver_mail'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:413:in `deliver_mail'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mail-2.5.3/lib/mail/message.rb:229:in `deliver'
from (irb):6
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in
```

Here is the setup_mail.rb file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "domain",
  :user_name            => "user@gmail.com",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Is it an issue with the port? If so, which port should I use and why?

How can I solve this timeout error? How can I get around firewalls?
Any help and suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you are in a local interanet with a firewall, you need to open the ports on the firewall to allow the SMTP access.

Comment: Depends on your use case, if you just need to try and send a mail you could use ssh forwarding,

if it's due to security restriction on deployment with a client, see with their security officer how to resolve the issue. You can, if needed, dislocate the mail sending to a different server by using DelayedJob for example

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something or where the production server is that it's behaviour changes depending on your location? WTF?